# ng-resource parameterized url not working for post

Tags: angularjs

when i am attempting to save this resource the url that ends up getting called is:  http://localhost:8080/api/apps/configs.  when i change the save to a get it works fine.

```
$scope.appconfig = {}
/**
* save the current configuration
*/
$scope.saveConfig = function() {

var Config = $resource('api/apps/:appid/:version/:env/:site/configs');

Config.save({
    appid : sel.app.name,
    version : sel.version,
    env : sel.env.name,
    site: sel.site.id,
    configs: $scope.appconfig
}, function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
})

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the mappings, as shown below:

```
var Config = $resource('api/apps/:appid/:version/:env/:site/configs', {
  appid: '@appid',
  version: '@version',
  env: '@env',
  site: '@site',
  configs: '@configs'
});
```

**Updated Again:**

What you are asking for, kind of goes against the ngResource pattern but this should do the trick.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngResource']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Config) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.appconfig = {
    purple: 'monkey',
    dishwasher: true
  };

  var sel = {
    app: {
      name: 'foo'
    },
    version: '0.0.1',
    env: {
      name: 'bar'
    },
    site: {
      id: '1234-5678-90'
    }
  };

  /**
   * save the current configuration
   */
  $scope.saveConfig = function() {
    Config.save({
      appid: sel.app.name,
      version: sel.version,
      env: sel.env.name,
      site: sel.site.id,
      configs: $scope.appconfig
    }).then(function(resp) {
      console.log(resp);
    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

  };
});

app.factory('Config', function($http, $resource) {
  return $resource('api/apps/:appid/:version/:env/:site/configs', {
      appid: '@appid',
      version: '@version',
      env: '@env',
      site: '@site'
    }, {
      save: {
        method: 'POST',
        transformRequest: [function(request) {
          return {
            configs: request.configs
          };
        }].concat($http.defaults.transformRequest)
      }
    });
});
```

Here is a plunker to demonstrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/BBwkxPyU6kQ0FLYzzb3V?p=preview

Comment: thanks for the response,  this does resolve the path problem,  however when doing this it post all of this data into the body of the request.  i only want the configs in the body the rest of those params should be used for the path resolution

Comment: thanks again for your very detailed answer,  can you explain what i am mis using,  i have a path that i want to post data to,  the path has been templated.  how would you handle this in a more proper way for ngResource?  thanks again

Comment: No problem. As for the pattern, read this http://blog.mgechev.com/2014/02/05/angularjs-resource-active-record-http/ One way to clean up your implementation would be to use an Abstract Factory pattern to create the resource. Then you could use the Active Record pattern, as intended.